# How to read multiple sigValues from CAN using Python COM API?

Tags: python, canoe, pythoncom

I have followed this tutorial to open and start a measurement in CANoe using python COM: https://simulation4vehicle.blogspot.com/2018/09/python-3-canoe-via-com-api.html. This works fine to read one signal value from CANoe using get_SigVal function. My question is, how could I read multiple signal values or even a message? Because if i call the get_SigVal function for each signal that I need, when I need 10 signals the reading is heavy and rare.

Comment: There is no other way (when using COM). For each signal value you want to get, you have to call `GetSignal` once.

Comment: But that means for me losing messages, is there a way I can parallelize so I don't lose so many messages?

Comment: Don't use COM. The COM api is meant for controlling CANoe from outside, not for any realtime measurements and such.

Comment: do you know an alternative from python or c/c++?